# Insert a field after matching pattern

Tags: perl, sed, awk

I'd like to search for a specific pattern in a file and then insert a field into the line with the matching pattern.  For example, I'd like to search for the pattern `HELLO` and then insert a word `NEW` after 2nd `,`.

infile.txt

```
HELLO (A0[], B0[],C0,D0, E0)
HELLO (A1[], B1[],C1,D1, E1)
...
HELLO (Aj[], Bj[],Cj,Dj, Ej)
```

outfile.txt should be:

```
HELLO (A0[], B0[], NEW, C0,D0, E0)
HELLO (A1[], B1[], NEW, C1,D1, E1)
...
HELLO (Aj[], Bj[], NEW, Cj,Dj, Ej)
```

thanks

Comment: The inevitable question, what have you tried?

Comment: I tried this:  find . -name "infile.txt" -print | xargs sed -i "/HELLO/ s/^\(.*\)\(,\)/\1, NEW\2/"  but the output came out as: HELLO (data0, data1, data2, data3, NEW, data4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this `awk`,

```
awk -F, '/HELLO/{ $3=" NEW, "$3;}1' OFS=, infile.txt > outfile.txt
```

Comment: I tried awk -F, '/HELLO/{ $3=" NEW, "$3;}1' OFS=, infile.txt > outfile.txt and it works nicely.  It's independent of what field 2 is. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

The following produces your desired output:

```
perl -pe 's/^HELLO.+?,.+?,\K/ NEW, /' infile.txt > outfile.txt
```

Hopt this helps!

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/HELLO/s/,/, NEW,/2' file
```

Answer (score 2):

```
perl -pe 's|HELLO(.+?,){2}\K| NEW, |' file
```

output

```
HELLO (A0[], B0[], NEW, C0,D0, E0)
HELLO (A1[], B1[], NEW, C1,D1, E1)
HELLO (Aj[], Bj[], NEW, Cj,Dj, Ej)
```

Answer (score 1):

Updating as per your updated question.

```
$ cat infile.txt
HELLO (A0[], B0[],C0,D0, E0)
HELLO (A1[], B1[],C1,D1, E1)
HELLO (A2[], B1[],C2,D2, E2)
HELLO (A3[], B3[],C3,D3, E3)
HELLO (A4[], B4[],C4,D4, E4)
HELLO (A5[], B5[],C5,D5, E5)

$ sed -i '' '/^HELLO/s/\(B[0-9]\[]\),/\1, NEW, /' infile.txt

$ cat infile.txt
HELLO (A0[], B0[], NEW, C0,D0, E0)
HELLO (A1[], B1[], NEW, C1,D1, E1)
HELLO (A2[], B1[], NEW, C2,D2, E2)
HELLO (A3[], B3[], NEW, C3,D3, E3)
HELLO (A4[], B4[], NEW, C4,D4, E4)
HELLO (A5[], B5[], NEW, C5,D5, E5)
```

Comment: +1 though `g` might be un-necessary and you can do `/& NEW,/` in replacement part.

Comment: Fails for `B122[]` or `B3AC[]` and you have a pair of `''` extra, that makes it fails and not change anything.

Answer (score 1):

This `sed` should take care of all:

```
cat file
HELLO (A0[], B0[],C0,D0, E0, G0[])
HELLO (A1[], B1[],C1,D1, E1, G1[])
...
HELLO (A122[], B122[],C122,D122, E122, G122[])
HELLO (A32C[], B32C[],C32C,D32C, E32C, G32C[])
HELLO (Aj[], Bj[],Cj,Dj, Ej, Gj[])
```

```
sed '/^HELLO/s/B[^[]*\[\],/& NEW, /' file
HELLO (A0[], B0[], NEW, C0,D0, E0, G0[])
HELLO (A1[], B1[], NEW, C1,D1, E1, G1[])
...
HELLO (A122[], B122[], NEW, C122,D122, E122, G122[])
HELLO (A32C[], B32C[], NEW, C32C,D32C, E32C, G32C[])
HELLO (Aj[], Bj[], NEW, Cj,Dj, Ej, Gj[])
```

It will work with any number or letter after `B`, like `B122` `B12AB` etc
The non greedy `[^[]*` is better to us than `.*`, since it will fail if there are other brackets like  `G1[]`

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
sed '/^HELLO/s/B[0-9a-zA-Z]\+\[\],/& NEW, /' file
```

```
$ cat file
HELLO (A0[], B0[],C0,D0, E0)
HELLO (A1[], B1[],C1,D1, E1)
HELLO (Aj[], Bj[],Cj,Dj, Ej)
```

```
sed '/^HELLO/s/B[0-9a-zA-Z]\+\[\],/& NEW, /' file
HELLO (A0[], B0[], NEW, C0,D0, E0)
HELLO (A1[], B1[], NEW, C1,D1, E1)
HELLO (Aj[], Bj[], NEW, Cj,Dj, Ej)
```

Comment: Fails for `B122[]` or `B3AC[]`